# fixing the warning message "Name 'something' can be undefined"

Tags: python, warnings

i just started learning to code with python and i wanted to create a program that repeatedly reads integers until the user enters “done”. Once “done” is entered i wanted the program to print out the sum, count, and average of the integers that were entered into the program.
like this:

```
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: bad data
Invalid input
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: done
16 3 5.333333333333333
```

i managed to create it with the following code

```
count = 0
add = 0
while True:
    try:
        y = input("enter a number: ")
        if count != 0 and y == "done":
            print(f"count:{count}\nsum:{add}\navg:{avg}")
            break
        elif count == 0 and y == "done":
            print(f"count:{count}\nsum:{add}\navg:Invalid")
            break
        else:
            y = int(y)
            count = count + 1
            add = add + y
            avg = add / count
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input")
```

which after plugging the same values from the example, returns.

```
enter a number: 4
enter a number: 5
enter a number: bad data
invalid input
enter a number: 7
enter a number: done
count:3
sum:16
avg:5.333333333333333
```

but in PyCharm (the IDM i am using) it shows a warning message stating "the variable 'avg' can be undefined", now i take it to mean that, the IDM thinks that there is a way in which after some kind of input the variable 'avg' is undefined. yet i don't know how to remake the code so that the variable 'avg' is always defined (in short: i want to make the warning message disappear), and please feel free to improve on my code and tell me how and why, it will be much appreciated.

i understood that it might be because the IDM thinks that if the first IF statement were to be TRUE on the first time the program ran then the program will end without the 'avg' variable being defined.
and so i figured that if i defined the variable 'avg' somewhere in the beginning before the first IF statement then it would stop showing the warning message, but i couldn't define it in the beginning because the count variable was still 0 and it would mean dividing by zero.

Comment: Well done trying to reason through this. The specific problem is likely to be with the statement `print(f"count:{count}\nsum:{add}\navg:{avg}")`. Is that the statement PyCharm highlights? If so, it's warning that that statement could be executed before you define `avg`, because it's unable to figure out that `count != 0` in fact guarantees that `avg` has been defined.

Comment: You won't divide by 0 because you do the division after `count = count + 1`. Just add the default value for `avg`. The IDE isn't clever enough to figure out that the logic prevents `avg` from being used before it's assigned.

Comment: btw, it's IDE (Integrated Development Environment), not IDM.

Comment: You can initialize `avg` to `0` without actually dividing by `count`. (For that matter, you could initialize it to *anything*, because the first time it matters a meaningful value will be assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in computing the average repeatedly during the loop. Wait until *after* the loop exits to compute it.

```
count = 0
add = 0
while True:
    y = input("enter a number: ")
    if y == "done":
        break

    try:
        y = int(y)
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input")
        continue

    count += 1
    add += y

if count == 0:
    avg = "invalid"
else:
    avg = add / count

print(f"count:{count}\nsum:{add}\navg:{avg}")
```